# Why do i need cglib (Spring AOP) to have multiple test classes?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-aop

I have a **spring application** 
and I make my test class as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class MyTest {

}
```

When I try to create another test class and tried to run the application, I get the following exception on the new test class:

```
ERROR [main] (TestContextManager.java:324) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecut
r@22e85825] to prepare test instance [Testing.MyTest2@43f2f70a]
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport.createAopProxy(ProxyCreatorSupport.java:104)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:111)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

This exception was solved by adding cglib to my classpath, but I want to understand why multiple test classes needs the cglib?

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Does your "another test" use the same `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: yes, since i need both tests to use same database configuration which exists in applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring requires the CGLIB jars because it's using CGLIB to proxy your beans. This happens if you configure spring to use this mechanism in your applicationContext.xml or if Spring needs to proxy a class which implements no interfaces. The Spring documentation for this is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) and provides a very clear explantation.

In order to use JDK dynamic proxies ensure that any proxied classes implement an appropriate interface and that you're not forcing Spring to use CGLIB through configuration.

Comment: The need for CGLIB "if Spring needs to proxy a class which implements no interfaces" was news to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that spring adds its to your class at runtime, and this is why it need the cglib library (it is used for bytecode manipulation and code injection, see [here](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/))

Answer (score 0):

Spring definately will use the proxy mechanism for some of your classes.

But, as of Spring version 3.2 the [CGLIB sources are repackaged](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) and added to the spring-core by default, so you don't need to add the CGLIB library to your classpath manually.

By the way, as the [spring blog entry](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/) of Michael Isvy and [this issue report](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5654) state, the CGLIB project is not active any more. In future versions Spring will use Javassist by default.