# Spring Boot Data JPA issues with DB/2 Configuration and JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data, autowired

I am working on a project which wants to use spring-boot-data-jpa.  The local (IDE) database can be H2.  However, for all servers (dev/test/prod), we are forced to use DB/2 (unfortunately!).

We can't seem to get it things working with DB/2.   We get an error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No   
qualifying bean of type [...Repository] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

when running the unit tests (JUnit). Note, the blank {} annotation.  Which on the face of it seems like an "obvious" issue.   The repository bean can not be loaded or found on the classpath.  However, when we run this with H2 configuration, it works just fine.

So, the next logical conclusion seems to be the repositories configuration (data source, etc.) is not set up correctly.  However, we can use the same configuration values in a non spring boot application and it works fine!

So then I was thinking it could be something with the either the differing classloaders or cglib proxies not using the "real" implementation class.  SO questions like these:

- [Spring data autowire issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686042/autowiring-issue-with-junit-in-a-spring-data-jpa-environment)
- [CGLIB needed for Spring Junit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865524/why-do-i-need-cglib-spring-aop-to-have-multiple-test-classes/7865714#7865714)
- [Autowire and eclipse can cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627300/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed-when-trying-to-create-a-test/12627512#12627512)

However, the correct answers for those questions do not resolve the issue.   So here is my post/question.

How do figure out the root cause of this issue?  I have tried to walk through the code (spring and our code) in the debugger but can't narrow down a cause.

So then I tried this, I took the sample spring boot jpa and modified it to use specific properties for DB/2 and I can get the same failure.  So it seems like my configuration must be wrong or there is a bug in the spring code.   I have looked at the configuration with someone else and we don't see the problem.  We tried this configuration in another (non-spring boot app) and it works.

Here is a [patch file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8101330) that shows the differences between the original jpa sample and the modified one with the configuration changes.   Note, we removed the DB2 server details.  Hopefully, this makes the issue reproducible for anyone and then can assist in figuring out the cause.

TIA,

Scott

edit 1 --- add configuration details here directly instead of a patch file ---

Java Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SampleDataJpaApplication {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     SpringApplication.run(SampleDataJpaApplication.class, args);
     }
 }
```

Properties File

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform: DB2Platform
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true

spring.datasource.driverClassName: om.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:db2:someDB2-db:5000
spring.datasource.username: fakeuser
spring.datasource.password: fakepassword
spring.datasource.schema:schema-name
```

Unit Test Configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SampleDataJpaApplication.class, loader =       AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class CityRepositoryIntegrationTests {
 //....
}
```

This should be nearly identical to the patch file just changing the user/password/jdbc URL to hide the specifics of the environment.

Comment: Sharing your configuration would be helpful.

Comment: @OliverGierke - Thank you for the quick reply.  I have provided a patch file that should alter the spring-data sample application with all of the changes including the configuration.  Does that work for you?  Would it be better to just post the Java configuration directly here?

Comment: Post what you have here, please.

Comment: @OliverGierke - updated the post to inline the configuration changes made to the sample JPA application.  These should be identical to the patch provided.  Let me know what else I can provide to get closer figuring out root cause.   -- Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oliver,

I can't seem to find the annotation `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` using the spring-boot-starter-test JAR as defined in the how-to.  I'm using spring boot 0.5.0.M6.  Below are the dependencies in my Maven POM.  Anything I'm missing here?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**: After looking through the Spring Boot sample projects I found a different approach to getting Junit and Spring test to play nicely with each other.  If you can define your class like the following things should work identical to what Oliver has mentioned in his reply for option 1. Notice the "loader" argument needs to be present to correctly configure listeners and backing beans correctly.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyDataApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the JUnit setup is not correct. To let Boot work correctly you have two choices:

1. **Use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`**

   Boot configures the `ApplicationContext` bootstrap process quite a bit, e.g. to enable the default configuration files being picked up. Using the custom annotation will automatically activate that stuff for the JUnit executions as well.
2. **Configure `@ContextConfiguration` with the appropriate listeners yourself**

   In your case you at least need the `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` in addition to all the default ones registered.

As the second option is rather cumbersome, I highly recommend to go with option one and see where that leads you.

Comment: What is @SpringApplicationConfiguration ?

Comment: See [the codebase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.java). It's effectively a replacement for `@ContextConfiguration` in integration tests for Boot based apps. You pull in the JAR by including `spring-boot-starter-test` or the `spring-boot` JAR with the classifier `tests`.

Comment: Thanks you! :) After your post I find this: http://presos.dsyer.com/decks/spring-boot-intro.html#slide50

Comment: Good one, although it actually pre-dates (and actually let to the creation of) `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Comment: Can you post example with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`? This not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with integration tests in Spring Boot and I can confirm @user3166395 solution.

This configuration works for me:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyDataApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

   @Autowired
   CityRepository cityRepository;

}
```

This requires test dependency to:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:0.5.0.M7
```

I cant achieve working test with `SpringApplicationConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys a little late to the party but to be clear about your error (since I copied it, I had the same):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: **om**.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

should be

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: **com**.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

This worked for me so far.